# after holding a key for a while I can't type until i close and re-open the app

Tags: macos, keyboard, osx-el-capitan

This started happening lately, I am on a Mac OS X El Capitan, v10.11.4.

If I hold a key a few seconds pressed, It doesn't matter which app I am using, I can't continue typing. I have to close and re-open the app, or if it's a browser tab I have to do the same for that particular tab. But the meta keys or key combos continue to work.

I don't recall changing a relevant setting, I checked the accesibility settings found nothing relevant either. I'd appreciate any pointers towards a solution. Thanks.

Comment: Does this happen on normal letter keys or just the meta keys?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Later versions of Mac OS have a feature (enabled by default) where an [accents, emoji, and symbols](https://support.apple.com/en-nz/HT201586) menu pops up when you press and hold certain characters.

The feature [doesn't seem to work properly](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7306504?tstart=0) for some folks and the issues being reported are similar if not identical to yours.

The solution, if you don't care for this "special characters" pop-up feature, is to disable it. Use Terminal to enter the following command, press Return, and then log out and back in:

`defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false`

So far as I can tell, you do *not* need to disable SIP to do this.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I thought it'd be related but this didn't seem to solve the issue :/

Comment: actually this fixed the issue after setting it back to false. You deserve more than this bounty good sir! Thank you.